# Sumar values de los checkbox seleccionados y mostrarlos en un input javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hola buenas tengo esta duda en este ejercicio de javascript, quiero hacer que los checkbox del formulario sumen sus respectivos values en el producto final, ya hice en js una funcion que mostrara el value del producto en el presupuesto final, mi duda es como haria para que me sume cuando el usuario marque un checkbox y este sume al monto del presupuesto final muchas gracias

```
            <!--Formulario de Datos-->
            <fieldset class="formulario">
                <legend>Presupuesto</legend>
                <label>Producto:</label> <select onchange="mostrarprecio()" id="producto">
                    <option>Elige Una Opcion</option>
                    <option id="patinete" value="200">Patinete Xiaomi 200€</option>
                    <option id="movil" value="800">Xiaomi Mi11 800€</option>
                    <option id="tablet"  value="400">Ipad 400€</option>
                    </select><br> <br>
                <label id="extras">Extras </label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="funda" value="30">Funda
                <input type="checkbox" name="protec" value="10">Protector de Pantalla 
                <input type="checkbox" name="Seguro" value="50">Seguro <br> <br> 
                <label>Presupuesto Final:</label>
                <input type="text" id="preciofinal">
                <br> 
            </fieldset>
            <br>
            <fieldset class="formulario">
                <legend>Aceptación de Condiciones y Envió de Formulario </legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="aceptar" required />Acepta la "Política de Privacidad" de la
                Empresa <br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="boton" value="Enviar Formulario"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Borrar Todo" onload="precio()" />
        </form>
        </fieldset>
    </main>
    <br><br><br>
    <hr>
    <!--Contacto para redes sociales-->
    <footer>
        <nav class="copy">Todos los Derechos Reservados© 2021 <br>
            <img src="../assets/imagenes/facebook.png" alt="social" id="redes1" />
            <img src="../assets/imagenes/instragram.png" alt="social" id="redes2" />
        </nav>
    </footer> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /*Script del presupuesto*/
    /* Ejecucion de la funcion */
    function mostrarprecio(){
            let producto = document.getElementById('producto');
            let   preciofinal = document.getElementById('preciofinal');
            
            preciofinal.value = producto.value;
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```